# Updating calculated field formula via CSOM with non-english regional settings fails with "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported."

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, csom, calculated-column-formula

In our current project we programmatically provision site collections, site columns and content types using CSOM/PnP. During this provisioning process the initial locale id is switched from 1033 to 1031 ("German (Germany)") for the web.

One of our columns is a calculated site column that's being used in a content type which is being attached to a list. Provisioning / updating the site column formula fails if the locale id is set to 1031 although the exact same formula can be successfully inserted via web UI, so the question is: why does it fail when CSOM is used? (It also works using SSOM PowerShell on-premises, but we're focusing on SPO here.)

We are aware of the localizing aspects of calculated column formulas, so we use semi-colons instead of commas as function parameter delimiters.

During our tests I tried to narrow down the problem. Updating the formula with a trivial one (like `=1` or `="Hello world!"` or `=[Title]`) always works, regardless of the web locale id. As soon as I use a slightly more complex one like `=CONCATENATE(Title;" (Hello World!)")` it fails for the 1031 locale id, which is unexpected. Localizing the function name to the german `VERKETTEN` also never works. (Note that this is only a simple example to demonstrate the problem, our actual formula is slightly more complex and uses other functions and fields.)

Here's an overview on what I'm doing in our test scenario, inspired by the workaround in the [github issue 1236 ("Calculated colums in site with language other than EN (NL in my case) are not provisioned correctly.")](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1236):

1. We create the calculated column using [AddFieldAsXml](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee537029(v=office.15)) on the webs FieldCollection using the default locale id 1033 and the formula `=CONCATENATE([Title]," (initial version)")`. This works fine.
2. We add the column to a newly created content type and add that content type to a newly created list. This works fine.
3. We change the `Web.RegionalSettings.LocaleId` to 1031. No problem here.
4. We reload the calculated column from the `Web.Fields` collection and update the column formula to `=CONCATENATE([Title];" (second version)")` using [`FieldCalculated.UpdateAndPushChanges(true)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sp-pnp-dotnet/ee544879(v=office.15)). This fails: `The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.`
5. We try the same operation using the calculated column from the `List.Fields` collection, again updating the the column formula to `=CONCATENATE([Title];" (second version)")`. This also fails: `The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.`
6. We open the web UI to modify the site column properties and insert the calculated formula `=CONCATENATE([Title];" (second version)")` there. This works fine.

I am stumped why the same formula works using the web UI but not via CSOM. What am I missing? Did we find a SharePoint bug?